# Spring Eureka server does not find context-path in client url

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

When a client application is registered into Spring Eureka server the client id appears at dashboard, but the link url only contains the hostname and port without the context-path of client.

If I create the Spring Boot client application without setting a context-path, I mean default root context, Eureka server can access all actuators available in there.

Is there any way to inform Eureka server about it? I tried to set health and info properties,  but it did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your Eureka client is setup via Spring's `@EnableEurekaClient`, then the client will default the health check and status check to `/health` and `/info` respectively.  (These paths may be the default values beyond the Spring `@EnableEurekaClient` setup, but I am unfamiliar with those at this point in time).

You can override these defaults by setting the following properties:

> eureka.instance.statusPageUrlPath
>
> eureka.instance.healthCheckUrlPath

The [Spring Cloud Documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/docs/1.0.x/spring-cloud.html#_status_page_and_health_indicator) contains this information, plus much more.

Comment: You're right,  I found out in there,  see "if you use a non-default context path or servlet path (e.g. server.servletPath=/foo) or management endpoint path (e.g. management.contextPath=/admin)"

Answer (score 0):

> application.yml

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /your-path
```